# NAPTR DNS record pointing to a data URI?

Tags: domain-name-system, https, http, rewrite, dns-record

Do web browsers consider NAPTR records in DNS resolution? If so, could you set one up to point a domain name to a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) e.g. `data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==`? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, and it doesn't even make sense "to point a domain name to a data URL".

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, NAPTR lets you specify a URI.

Comment: On another note, which record types are considered by browser DNS resolvers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do web browsers consider NAPTR records in DNS resolution?

No, I don't think they do. Why would/should they?
(`NAPTR` were (are?) mostly used around ENUM and telephony stuff, in tandem with `SRV` record types, which ones are also specifically not used by browsers - if they were we wouldn't have to need to create `HTTPS` record types see at bottom)

What are you attempting to do, specifically when speaking about using an URL or data URL?

As for your other comments:

> Well, NAPTR lets you specify a URI.

Other records do, too. Including the `URI` record type (RFC 7553). That no one uses.

> On another note, which record types are considered by browser DNS resolvers?

Difficult to be 100% authoritative without having to check all source code of all browsers. Good luck to anyone wanting to do that. I am fairly certain you can discover some skeletons in the closet.

Do also note that:

1. browsers are doing DOH now, so potentially retrieving more data/record type than before (one of the argument of DOH, even if minor, is that it allows a "richer" DNS experience as it is then able to ask for anything instead of relying on the OS that provides basically only final resolution that is `A`/`AAAA` records
2. there are new record types around the corner, `HTTPS` and `SVCB`, which some browsers/OS already said to use